# Javascript function won't yield expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a Javascript function that is supposed to yield the item's nth child. Below is the code for the function.

```js
function findNthChild(element) {
 nthchild = 1;
 console.log(element);
 if (element.prev().hasClass('.point')) {
  while (element.prev().hasClass('.point')) {
   nthchild++;
   element == element.prev()
  }
  return nthchild;
 }
 else {
  console.log('lmao');
  return 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: `element = element.prev();` instead `element == element.prev();`

Comment: Is `element` a jQuery object or a DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

From your element, the algorithm you want might look something like this

1. Look at the next sibling element, `elm`
2. If `elm` is *undefined* or *null* return `null`
3. If `elm` has class *interestingClass*, decrease `n` by `1`
4. If `n` is greater than `0` go back to step 1
5. Return `elm`

Vanilla,

```
function nthSiblingElementByClass(sibling, n, cls) {
    if (sibling) do {
        if (sibling.classList.contains(cls))
            if (--n < 0) return sibling;
    } while (sibling && (sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling));
    return null;
}
```

Usage, e.g. on this page

```
var elm = document.querySelector('.kwd');
nthSiblingElementByClass(elm, 5, 'pln'); // <span class=​"pln">​console​</span>​
```

Comment: How would this spit out what nth child it is? Also can you provide like a jsfiddle or an example so I can understand the usage better.